# Email template design inconsistency

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have an email template for gmx and the images are overflowing the `div`. I would like to know how can I avoid overflowing so that design remain consistent. Here's the [link](https://codepen.io/bahag-hamidk/pen/QWmWBoa?editors=1010) to a codepen I created.

[This is how its overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/symB9.png)

Comment: Use them as background images, then you can have just empty div's with required dimensions

Comment: you mean instead of img tag i rather use div with background-image. Isn't that going to put the image in the background and text on the front?

Comment: No, because you will set `<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-image: url()"></div><font face="Helvetica, Arial" style="color : #666; ....`

Comment: AH thanks it worked but now I have to align it to center without using flex as flex is not working in email templates

Comment: `text-align: center` or `margin: 0 auto;`